# Can we conclude that $v|_{K^*}$ is surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology

[image]

From the definition of discrete valuation, can we conclude that $v|_{K^*}$ is surjective?

Comment: No, imagine doubling a given $v$'s values.

Comment: Your book is quite sloppy because in p-adics we often normalize the valuation such that $v_p(p)=1$ which means the discrete valuation on $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n})$ is $\frac1n\Bbb{Z}$ valued

Comment: This is the usual definition of a valuation. Nothing "sloppy" here.

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is a valuation, so is $k v$ for any $k\in\mathbf{N}^*$, so there's no chance a valuation is necessarily surjective.